# PHP LDAP login script

Tags: php, ldap

I'm new to LDAP binding script, I'm trying to check if the script I found is correct to be able to use it back on my company as LDAP authentication script, for this I'm using this https://documize.github.io/ad-ldap-test-server/, everything seems to be working but the only way I get through the authentication is using something like this: `CN=Mr Manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local` as username. When I use the username itself for instance (Mr Manager) get the message: "Unable to login: Invalid credentials".

Something is missing, something not resolving the username but I can't get it, here the code I'm using.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('DOMAIN_FQDN', 'DC=mycompany,DC=local');
define('LDAP_SERVER', 'documize-ad.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com');

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password']; //Pass@word1!

    $conn = ldap_connect("ldap://".LDAP_SERVER."/",389);

    if (!$conn)
        $err = 'Could not connect to LDAP server';

    else
    {
        //define('LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE', 0x0032);

        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        $bind = @ldap_bind($conn, $user, $pass);

        ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error);

        if (!empty($extended_error))
        {
            $errno = explode(',', $extended_error);
            $errno = $errno[2];
            $errno = explode(' ', $errno);
            $errno = $errno[2];
            $errno = intval($errno);

            if ($errno == 532)
                $err = 'Unable to login: Password expired';
        }

        elseif ($bind)
        {
            $base_dn = array("CN=*,DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)), 
                "DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)));

            $result = ldap_search(array($conn,$conn), $base_dn, "(CN=*)");

            if (!count($result))
                $err = 'Unable to login: '. ldap_error($conn);

            else
            {
                foreach ($result as $res)
                {
                    $info = ldap_get_entries($conn, $res);

                    for ($i = 0; $i < $info['count']; $i++)
                    {
                        if (isset($info[$i]['displayName']) AND strtolower($info[$i]['displayName'][0]) == strtolower($user))
                        {
                            session_start();

                            $username = explode('@', $user);
                            $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';

                            // set session variables...

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // session OK, redirect to home page
    if (isset($_SESSION['foo']))
    {
        header('Location:"index.php"');
        exit();
    }

    elseif (!isset($err)) $err = 'Unable to login: '. ldap_error($conn);

    ldap_close($conn);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Login</title></head>
<style>
* { font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; }
.errmsg { color: red; }
#loginbox { font-size: 12px; }
</style>
<body>
<div align="center"><img id="imghdr" src="img/logo.jpg" height="300" /><br><br><h2>CREDENTIALS</h2><br><br>

<div style="margin:10px 0;"></div>
<div title="Login" style="width:500px" id="loginbox">
    <div style="padding:10px 0 10px 0px">
    <form action="login.php" id="login" method="post">
        <table><?php if (isset($err)) echo '<tr><td colspan="2" class="errmsg">'. $err .'</td></tr>'; ?>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" autocomplete="off"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" autocomplete="off"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at `$base_dn` before you try and use it...

Comment: Miken32, `$base_dn` do mean this `DC=mycompany,DC=local`?

Comment: I mean, what is the second argument to [`ldap_search()`](https://php.net/ldap_search) supposed to be, and is what you are passing to it the right thing? (Hint: no, it's not!)

Comment: Found something but as already said, it's the first time I'm using LDAP Bind: `$base_dn = array("sAMAccountName=$user,DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)), 
                "DC=". join(',DC=', explode('.', DOMAIN_FQDN)));

            $result = ldap_search(array($conn,$conn), $base_dn, "sAMAccountName=$user");`

Comment: Ok, it seems to be more difficult than expected, it doesn't work, never mind I will look for something else.

Comment: The docs pretty clearly stated the second argument should be a string. And if you aren’t comfortable enough with LDAP to understand what the base DN signifies you should do some reading in that area before proceeding.

Comment: Thx for your help Miken32, for sure I will once I have the time to do so, I just needed this once.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to implement a LDAP login is:

1. Bind with an application user to the LDAP server
2. Search for the user's entry with the user name, e.g. with a filter like `(uid=<username>)` or in case of MS AD `(sAMAccountName=<username>)`
3. Use the DN of the found user entry as bind-DN in a new bind request

Security:

1. Don't forget disambiguation check when processing user search results! Only process the login if the search returns **exactly** one user entry.
2. Refuse empty password input as failed login! Some LDAP servers will happily return LDAP result code *ok(0)* when using empty password in a bind request.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: Read his question: "everything seems to be working but the only way I get through the authentication is using something like this: CN=Mr Manager,CN=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local as username"